# pushViewController call from uiview

Tags: iphone, uiview, pushviewcontroller

let me explain you my problem:

I have an UIViewController with 2 UIViews.
I have a button in one of my UIView and i call a methode from my UIViewController.

```
    [controller actionMainSettings];
```

And this is the methode:

```
-(void)actionMainSettings{
     MainSettings *mainController = [[MainSettings alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainSettings" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainController animated:YES];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [mainController release];   
}
```

MainSettings is an UIVewController...

and nothing happen...

When i put my button in my UIVIewController (`[self.view addSubview:buttonSettings];`)    it's ok but i want to put it in another UIView.

Can someone explain me what happen?

thx

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about this but you could try `super.navigationController` instead of `self`.
Also, from the look of your code, I would assume it's a settings view. I would recommend that you use `[self presentModalView:yourView animated:YES]`. You can look at the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for a range of animations.

Comment: i tried with [self presentModalView:yourView animated:YES] but nothing happen too :(

Comment: It probably has something to do with the initialization of your view, could you please post the code you use when you initialize your view? Also, did you create a new class for your view or are you alloc initing a default view class?

Comment: Forget it, I just realized it's already there, are you sure that the nib name you specified is there? If your view is a subclass of some other view and you checked the "With XIB for user interface" option when creating the files for your view then it doesn't make much sense to specify a NIB Name since it's already implied within your subclass...if so, you should alloc init it with the default initialization (e.g. `MainSettings *mainController = [[MainSettings alloc] init]`) and then pass it to the `presentModalView:animated:` method.

Comment: ok, one more thing, I'm really sorry, the method is `presentModalViewController`, not `presentModalView`, my bad, try it again taking into consideration everything I just said.

Comment: i put my methode in my Delegate and it's ok. thank you very much for your help ;)